# Regex: Match pattern unless preceded by pattern containing element from the matching character class

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am having a hard time coming up with a regex to match a specific case:

This can be matched:
`any-dashed-strings`
`this-can-be-matched-even-though-its-big`

This cannot be matched:
strings starting with **elem-** or **asdf-** or a single **-**
`elem-this-cannot-be-matched`
`asdf-this-cannot-be-matched`
`-`

So far what I came up with is:

```
/\b(?!elem-|asdf-)([\w\-]+)\b/
```

But I keep matching a single `-` and the whole `-this-cannot-be-matched` suffix. I cannot figure it out how to not only ignore a character present inside the matching character class conditionally, and not matching anything else if a suffix is found

I am currently working with the Oniguruma engine (Ruby 1.9+/PHP multi-byte string module).

If possible, please elaborate on the solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a lookbehind is supported, you can assert a whitespace boundary to the left, and make the alternation for both words without the hyphen optional.

```
(?<!\S)(?!(?:elem|asdf)?-)[\w-]+\b
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert the directly to the right is not

  - `(?:elem|asdf)?-` Optionally match `elem` or `asdf` followed by `-`
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `[\w-]+` Match 1+ word chars or `-`
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KkFN2T/1).

Or a version with a capture group and without a lookbehind:

```
(?:\s|^)(?!(?:elem|asdf)?-)([\w-]+)\b
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DUApo4/1).

Comment: Your first example did the trick! Thank you a lot, and thanks for the explanation.